# C++ get average colour of multible squares on screen (ambilight)

Tags: c++

Im new and i hope you can help me.
First some infos:
I wanna create a ambilight for my Keyboard(Roccat MK FX)
My Screen is 2560x1440.

I wanna split the screen in multible squares. For each Key on the board 1 square.
The board layout: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hvC3.png)
The Splitting of the screen(more or less):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxogH.png)

SOOO i wanna get the average colour of field "esc" and put it in the key "0" and so on.
I only have problems to get the colour of the screen.
I wanna only read every 10 pixel for speed and so on. maybe i lower it or so. i will see it later^^

the code is only for the top row of keys.
every square for a key has the dimension of 160x240 pixels for all 16 keys.

```
HDC hScreen = GetDC(0);
ScreenX = GetDeviceCaps(hScreen, HORZRES);
ScreenY = GetDeviceCaps(hScreen, VERTRES);

HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, ScreenX, ScreenY);
HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, hScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);

BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = { 0 };
bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.biBitCount = 32;
bmi.biWidth = ScreenX;
bmi.biHeight = -ScreenY;
bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmi.biSizeImage = 0;// 3 * ScreenX * ScreenY;

if (ScreenData)
    free(ScreenData);
ScreenData = (BYTE*)malloc(4*ScreenX * ScreenY);

GetDIBits(hdcMem, hBitmap, 0, ScreenY, ScreenData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

ReleaseDC(0, hScreen);
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);

if (tasta)
{
    //teiler = 1;
    redcolor = 0;
    greencolor = 0;
    bluecolor = 0;
    redtemp = 0;
    greentemp = 0;
    bluetemp = 0;
    hori = 0;
    vert = 0;
    memset(frame_dataOnOff, 0, 110);
    memset(frame_dataRed, 0, 110);
    memset(frame_dataGreen, 0, 110);
    memset(frame_dataBlue, 0, 110);
    x_cord = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k <= 15; k++)//eigne einteilung wählen
    {
        redcolor = 0;
        greencolor = 0;
        bluecolor = 0;
        teiler = 0;
        for (int y = 1440; y > 1200; y = y - 10)//VERTIKAL 1440      240
        {

            for (int x = 160 * k; x <= 160 * k + 160; x = x + 10)//Horizontal  2560     variable
            {
                redcolor = redcolor + ScreenData[4 * (((y)*ScreenX) + x) + 2];
                greencolor = greencolor + ScreenData[4 * (((y)*ScreenX) + x) + 1];
                bluecolor = bluecolor + ScreenData[4 * (((y)*ScreenX) + x)];
                teiler++;
            }
        }
        redcolor = redcolor / teiler;
        greencolor = greencolor / teiler;
        bluecolor = bluecolor / teiler;
        frame_dataOnOff[k] = 1;
        frame_dataRed[k] = redcolor;
        frame_dataGreen[k] = greencolor;
        frame_dataBlue[k] = bluecolor;
    }
    x_cord = 0;

    ReleaseDC(0, hScreen);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

with this code i get a error when k is 6 and x is 1010 error is: Ausgelöste Ausnahme: Lesezugriffsverletzung "ScreenData" war "0x62C511C". ScreenData for red = 14749642 
ScreenData for blue= 14749641 
ScreenData for green = 14749640 
I think im out of range or so. but dont know

Thx for help ;)

ps. when i change the multiplier from ScreenData from 4 to 3, the code works, but the colour squares ae on the wrong place. more in the left middle of the screen.

Comment: still looking for help^^

Comment: noone can help?